# Find documents that share one key but differ in another

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection that is resembles

```
{"dept":"A" , "email":"bob@example.com", "userID": "1"}
{"dept":"A" , "email":"bob@example.com", "userID": "1"}
{"dept":"A" , "email":"bob@example.com", "userID": "2"} <<< "bad" record
{"dept":"A" , "email":"alice@example.com", "userID": "3"}

{"dept":"B" , "email":"bob@example.com", "userID": "4"}
{"dept":"B" , "email":"kevin@example.com", "userID": "5"}
```

The constraint is that an email must only have a single userID per department.

How would I query the table to find which emails have multiple userIDs within a department? Mongo 4.4+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two `$group` pipeline stages to filter and find records with multiple entries.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "dept": "$dept",
        "email": "$email",
        "userID": "$userID",
      },
      "individualCount": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    },
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.email",
      "userIDs": {
        "$addToSet": "$_id.userID"
      },
      "dept": {
        "$addToSet": "$_id.dept"
      },
      "totalRecordsCount": {
        "$sum": "$individualCount"
      },
      "totalDuplicCounts": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
    },
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "totalDuplicCounts": {
        "$gt": 1
      }
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zRH0K0TFEmd)